# Saving the parsed data into an array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-multiple-selections-in-table-view-88dc2249c3a2)
, and currently i m trying to save the data in the array.  Actually this tutorial is doing what i m trying to do in my table . At the moment I m getting my data through this

```
class Conversations {
var id: Int?
var name: String?
var is_group: Int?
var photo: String?

init(fromDictionary dict: Dictionary<String,Any>) {
    if let tmp = dict["id"] as? Int {
        self.id = tmp
    }

    if let tmp = dict["name"] as? String {
        self.name = tmp
    }

    if let tmp = dict["is_group"] as? Int {
        self.is_group = tmp
    }

    if let tmp = dict["photo"] as? String {
        self.photo = tmp
    }
}

class func getModelArray(fromArray array: [[String:Any]]) -> [Conversations] {
    var conversations = [Conversations]()
    for row in array {
        conversations.append(Conversations(fromDictionary: row))
    }

    return conversations
}
```

In my `class GroupListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource` I've declared `var friendList = [Conversations]()` which is filled up from the json in the request `self.friendList = Conversations.getModelArray(fromArray: data)`

My question would be how to make it like in that tutorial , since he's hardcoded the array.

I've tried something like that from bellow but i receive

> Cannot convert value of type '[Conversations].Type' to expected argument type '[[String : Any]]' at dataArray. And to be honest I don t believe also that it s good

```
class Conversations {
var id: Int?
var name: String?
var is_group: Int?
var photo: String?

init(fromDictionary dict: Dictionary<String,Any>) {
    if let tmp = dict["id"] as? Int {
        self.id = tmp
    }

    if let tmp = dict["name"] as? String {
        self.name = tmp
    }

    if let tmp = dict["is_group"] as? Int {
        self.is_group = tmp
    }

    if let tmp = dict["photo"] as? String {
        self.photo = tmp
    }
}

class func getModelArray(fromArray array: [[String:Any]]) -> [Conversations] {
    var conversations = [Conversations]()
    for row in array {
        conversations.append(Conversations(fromDictionary: row))
    }

        return conversations
    }
}


class ViewModelConversations {
    private var conversations: Conversations

var isSelected = false
var id: Int? {
    return conversations.id
}

var name: String? {
    return conversations.name
}

var photo: String? {
    return conversations.photo
}

var is_group: Int? {
    return conversations.is_group
}

init(conversations: Conversations) {
    self.conversations = conversations
    }

}

let dataArray = [Conversations.getModelArray(fromArray: [Conversations])]

class ViewModel {
    var conversations = [ViewModelConversations]()
    init() {
        conversations = dataArray.map { ViewModelConversations(conversations: $0)}
    }
}
```

Appreciate.

Comment: Unrelated but why do you optional bind all dictionary values? All properties are optional anyway, so an extra optional binding is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

```
class func getModelArray(fromArray array: [[String:Any]]) -> [Conversations]
```

this function requires an array of dictionaries as input, bur you pass an array of Conversation objects to it in:

```
let dataArray = [Conversations.getModelArray(fromArray: [Conversations])]
```

so you need to have an array of dictionaries in order to initialize the `dataArray` constant